# Handling multiple objects in a remote JSON & performing CRUD to the content displayed as menu file using angular js

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, menu, single-page-application

I started learning angularjs two days back for making a menu from a remote json. I went through some basic tutorials. But got stuck when started coding for my requirement. I am facing the following challenges.

1.I understand that this could be a SPA and everybody wants SPA's in angularjs. Can i have some reasons why one should spent time learning this framework if it can be done using just HTML5 OR WHATEVER HE KNOWS.

2. My json has multiple obects. Three of them are arrays. And they have arrays within them. How to use $http and query to display this entire json maintaining this object-->array-->element heirarchy in a menu?
3. I want to have a side bar showing this heirarchy and need the menu of the corresponding object i selected to be displayed on the page. Should i use something like dynatable for this? Or is there any other alternative? Which is the best way to go about it.
   Any help is appreciated. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are some pretty good questions... where to start.

From my experience, you should decide if angularjs is the way you need to go. AngularJS is a fullstack frontend framework. I can honestly say that there were many times where angular was a bit of an overhead for the projects I have worked on. For example, if this is all you need to do, angularjs is too much for the task at hand. You can simply go with jQuery or whatever you are confortable with.
AngularJS is great with apps that are model oriented. If you application does heavy DOM manipulations than angular's directives can become a bit of a pain. And from my experience the learning curve is bumpy if you come from a jQuery background. If you have time to dig deep into angular I recommend you do so. But if time is not on your side I won't recommend you start a project with Angular. Nonetheless, Angular is a pretty framework to know.

Before starting with anuglar (don't learn it just because it's hyped and a cool framework and everybody talks about it), I strongly recommend going threw the basics of design patterns, modules in JS, OOP in JS and other basic concepts. These will help you understand angular on a whole different level and help you decide if angular is the right tool for you.

And to answer your menu related question, you can simply fetch the desired json like so:

```
// Simple GET request example :
$http.get('/someUrl').
  success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // this callback will be called asynchronously
    // when the response is available
  }).
  error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
    // called asynchronously if an error occurs
    // or server returns response with an error status.
  });
```

You can treat the response like any other json object and then you can build your menu structure like so

```
angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
   $scope.menu = ...
});
```

And for your sidebar you could make a directive:
Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp

something like so:

```
angular.module('yourapp')
   .directive('menu', function($http) {
      return {
          restrict: 'E',
          template: '<div ng-repeat="item in menu"></div>',
          link: function(scope, element, attr) {
              $http.get('/path/to/json')
                 .success(function(data) {
                     var menu = process_json_data(data);
                     $scope.menu = menu;
                 });
          }
      };
   });
```

*This is a rough sketch, if you will, a pseudo of the concept.*

Hope this helped.
Let me know!

Cheers

Comment: Lets say i have a json like
object {5}
 
FirstElement:0 

SecondElement:20

FirstArray[50]  

SecondArray[500] 

FifthElement {10}

Is it possible to access this json using $http.get('/someUrl') and manipulate it to get a menu the way you suggested?If yes,My bad stop reading. :). if no.. Whats the way to go about this.I read something and i was thinking query is what i should go with? Can you explain how? @Andrei Cacio

Comment: Well, if I understand it correctly, you can iterate that json and dinamically construct your menu. You can do a foreach on that json and check if the item is a string or number, create a li, if that item is an array than iterate that array an create an ul with li's and append that ul to your parent ul. Something like this?

Comment: The way you construct your menu can differ. You can create a recursive function that iterates your json and create chunks of HTML for your menu

Comment: The way you access your JSON is a pure javascript task and the way you build your menu is an Angular task. Which one is the problem?

Comment: Related to this doubt accessing the json is the problem. Because I can work fine with simple JSON files with single object array. I cant access it when more than one object is there in json.

Comment: Or you can say whats the difference between "get" and "query" with respect to the context that they are supposed to use. I think either could clear the doubt in my mind. :) @Andrei Cacio

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67617/discussion-between-andrei-cacio-and-rbz).

Answer (score 0):

1. think learning angular as an investment, you will achieve many tasks easier than pure html with jquery or similar combinations. i am not saying you will never need jquery or any other library ever but a framework like angular will help you in many ways. 2way model binding allows you to reflect model changes to view or view changes to model without any coding. MVC structure helps you to maintain clean code on client side. there are other benefits too. you should google which subjects angular can help you.
2. you can display whatever data you receive using model binding on angular. lets says your json response is below

   ```
   var response = {a: ['stack', 'overflow', 'com'], b: {d: 12, e:15}, c: { a: [1,2,3], b: 'test'}};
   ```

you can easily display this response as you wish on html

```
<span ng-repeat="data in response.a track by $index">{{data}}</span>
```

or you can build nested views.

3. you should read more about angular documentations. if you want to show some simple data you can bind to click event on menu and set some text to this data on your controller. if what you need is complex views with a left menu, you should go for seperate controllers and views.

you should start learning with angular tutorials